# Как компонент, обернутый в @observer, узнаёт, за какими свойствами следить?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Разбираюсь, как mobx работает внутри.
Интересует, как компонент узнаёт, что следить нужно за свойством store.test, и реагирует на изменения?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import store from 'store/index';

export default @observer class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {store.test}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observer` делает обертку над `render` компонента и подписывается на изменение данных, которые использовались при последнем рендере.

Comment: А как Observer понимает, какие данные используются/использовались в рендере?

Comment: При выполнении рендера происходит чтение значений observable (или computed) элементов.

Comment: Все равно не совсем понимаю. Именно тот момент, как observable "синхронизируется" c observer. Как observable узнаёт, какой именно observer нужно обновить?